# integrate a non-analytic function using Cauchy's formula

Tags: complex-analysis

How to integrate:
$$\int_{\gamma}  \frac{\lvert z\rvert e^z}{z^2}dz $$
where $\gamma$ is the circumference of the circle of radius 2 around the origin

Comment: On $\gamma$, $|z|=2$, so you can just use Cauchy's integral formula directly.

Comment: is $\lvert z\rvert e^z$ analytic on $\lvert z\rvert=2$? If it isn't, how do I use Cauchy's formula?

Comment: On $\gamma$, $|z|e^z=2e^z$, so you just need to deal with $2e^z$.

Comment: My bad, sorry, what a stupid question